# Can getStaticPaths accept dynamic slug(s)?

Tags: next.js

In a file called `pages/posts/[...slugs].tsx` I have the `getStaticPaths` function defined like this:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { slugs: ['1', 'hunt-for-the-hidden-reindeer'] } },
      { params: { slugs: ['1'] } },
    ],
    fallback: false
  };
}
```

How can I make the paths take in just `{ params: { slugs: ['1'] } }` and accept any other subsequent slugs that may come in. For example, serve the same static site for `/1`, `/1/hello`, and `1/random` using one rule. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not so clean. If you want to render the same page for some rule base URLs you can use [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites). But if you want to create a static page for some slugs within an array, there is no such thing that will generate. To achieve rendering same page for all `slug: /1`, `slug: /1/hello`, `slug: /1/random` etc. You should implicitly write in every element of paths array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Ahh okay, I tried to keep the question as simple as possible, may have left out some orienting details. I did not know about rewrites, I will use them. However, I can see how this is a valid use case for generating static paths, I wonder why this is not already a feature.